# Navigating from Page/ Page Function to PageFunction Null Reference Exception occurs

Tags: c#, wpf, pagefunction

Page.cs

```
private void PageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PageFunction pageFunction = new PageFunction();
    pageFunction.Return += new ReturnEventHandler<String>(pageFunction_Return);
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(pageFunction);
}

static void pageFunction_Return(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.ReturnEventArgs<String> e)
{
    String returnedVaule = e.Result;
    MessageBox.Show(returnedVaule);
}
```

PageFunction.cs

```
private void PageFunctionButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OnReturn(new ReturnEventArgs<string>("Returned"));
}
```

As Shown above i have a Page and a PageFunction.

On PageButton_Click of Page.cs, i am navigating to PageFunction, But after the execution of the whole PageButton_Click event, a null reference exception (i.e, Object reference not set to an instance of an object).

And i dont know why this exception ocurred.

Help me out with this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: use debugger to find the specific line/object (just check CLR-Exceptions in the Debug-settings)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had used debugger but the exception is not thrown from any line or Object from the code. So, didn't able to find from where exactly exception is thrown..

Comment: What's `OnReturn`? is it an event? If so, it could be the cause of the exception.

Comment: this is wpf, right? If this exception is thrown at runtime, the visual studio debugger will stop at the exception. If you have this disabled. Go to Debug->Exception->Check all. 

Events will throw Null if they are not subscripted to, you can try if(OnReturn != null) 
OnReturn(new Retu...);

Comment: Hurrey....I got the answer..the pageFunction_Return event by mistake has static keyword which should not be... the evnt will not be static and it should be declare as Public.   Tnak You for the Co-operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember -> `pagefunction<string>`
it may help you.